# Trying to pull the parameter of an object and give to another class(Unsure of title)

Tags: java, oop, object, methods

I am working on a school project where we are giving class files and are asked     to make more methods, and an overloaded version of one of the previous methods. I have created the code fine as far as i can tell, but i am unsure of how to inform the second class of a parameter of an object from the first class.

```
//Main Class
import SE111aClasses.*;
import SE112aClasses.*;
public class Coursework2
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        GUI gui = new GUI();
        MyRobot robby = new MyRobot();
        Room room = new Room(9); //Room 9 has some obstacles
        Picture picture = new Picture(room, robby);

        robby.move();
        picture.draw(room, robby);

        robby.move(4);
        picture.draw(room, robby);
    }
}    

//Side class with functions requiring information from main class
import SE111aClasses.*;
import SE112aClasses.*;
public class MyRobot extends Robot 
{
    public void move(int n)
    {
        GUI gui = new GUI();
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            if (!obstacle_ahead(room)) 
                {
                    move();
                }
            else
                {
                    gui.putText("Cannot move forward, obstacle in the way.");
                }
            }
        }
}
```

So, in the first class i have the line "Room room = new Room(9);". I need the second class to know that the first class is using the 9th room without passing it through the function. As in, i cant pass it through by doing "robby.move(Room room, 4)".

Anyone understand this and want to help?

The room class is very big, but ill post it to see if it helps.

```
package SE111aClasses;

/**
Base Room logic...
*/

public class Room {

    /**
    Creates a 20x20 empty room
    */
    public Room() {
        this(0);
    }

    /**
    Creates a 20x20 room of variable content

    @param identifier the exact room to be loaded
    */
    public Room (final int identifier) {
        grid = new int[size][size];
        init(identifier);
    }

    /**
    Room location (x/y) is made blank ( => WHITE )

    @param x the x coordinate of the grid reference
    @param y the y coordinate of the grid reference
    */
    public void setBlank (final int x, final int y) {
        grid[x][y] = WHITE;
    }

    /**
    Room location (x/y) is set as an unbreakable wall ( => BLACK )

    @param x the x coordinate of the grid reference
    @param y the y coordinate of the grid reference
    */
    public void setWall (final int x, final int y) {
        grid[x][y] = BLACK;
    }

    /**
    Room location (x/y) is set as an obstacle ( => BLUE )

    @param x the x coordinate of the grid reference
    @param y the y coordinate of the grid reference
    */
    public void setObstacle (final int x, final int y) {
        grid[x][y] = BLUE;
    }

    /**
    Room location (x/y) is set as an path ( => YELLOW )

    @param x the x coordinate of the grid reference
    @param y the y coordinate of the grid reference
    */
    public void setPath (final int x, final int y) {
        grid[x][y] = YELLOW;
    }

    /**
    Room location (x/y) is set as a target ( => GREEN )

    @param x the x coordinate of the grid reference
    @param y the y coordinate of the grid reference
    */
    public void setTarget (final int x, final int y) {
        grid[x][y] = GREEN;
    }

    /**
    Room location (x/y) is set to the color specified

    @param x the x coordinate of the grid reference
    @param y the y coordinate of the grid reference
    @param color the color to set the specified location to
    */
    public void setSquare (final int x, final int y, final String color) {
        if (color.compareTo("white")        == 0)   {grid[x][y] = WHITE;}
        else if (color.compareTo("black")   == 0)   {grid[x][y] = BLACK;}
        else if (color.compareTo("blue")    == 0)   {grid[x][y] = BLUE;}
        else if (color.compareTo("yellow")  == 0)   {grid[x][y] = YELLOW;}
        else if (color.compareTo("green")   == 0)   {grid[x][y] = GREEN;}
    }

    /**
    Room location (x/y) is set to the color specified

    @param x the x coordinate of the grid reference
    @param y the y coordinate of the grid reference
    @param color the color to set the specified location to
    */
    public void setSquare (final int x, final int y, final int color) {
        switch (color) {
            case 0:     grid[x][y] = WHITE;
                        break;
            case 1:     grid[x][y] = BLACK;
                        break;
            case 2:     grid[x][y] = BLUE;
                        break;
            case 3:     grid[x][y] = YELLOW;
                        break;
            case 4:     grid[x][y] = GREEN;
                        break;
            default:    break;
        }
    }

    public String toString () {
        StringBuffer state = new StringBuffer(1024);
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
            state.append(grid[x][y]).append(' ');
        }
        state.append("\n");
    }
    return state.toString();
}

/**
@return the size of the room
*/
protected final int room_size() {
    return size;
}

/**
@return the identity matrix that defines the room
*/
protected final int[][] getGrid() {
    return grid;
}

/**
@param grid the new identity matrix
*/
protected void setGrid (final int[][] grid) {
    this.grid = grid;
    size = grid.length;
}

/**
@return the 'state' (color) of the cell in question
*/
protected int cell_state (final int x, final int y) {
    if (x < 0 || x > room_size() || y < 0 || y > room_size()) {
        return -1;
    }
    return grid[x][y];
}

/**
@return true if the cell directly ahead is an obstacle (BLACK or BLUE square)
*/
protected boolean isObstacle (final int x, final int y) {
    if (grid[x][y] == BLUE || grid[x][y] == BLACK) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
Attempt to load the content of the room from the local filesystem. If the load fails,
create a standard empty room bordered by black walls

@param identifier the room content to be loaded
*/
private void init (final int identifier) {

    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
            if (x == 0 || (x == size - 1) || y == 0 || (y == size - 1))
                grid[x][y] = BLACK;
            else
                grid[x][y] = WHITE;
        }
    }

    switch (identifier) {
    case 1:
        grid[3][3] = 2;
        grid[4][3] = 2;
        grid[5][3] = 2;
        grid[6][3] = 2;
        grid[3][4] = 2;
        grid[5][4] = 4;
        break;

    case 2:
        grid[1][7] = 2;
        grid[2][7] = 2;
        grid[3][7] = 2;
        grid[4][7] = 2;
        grid[4][8] = 2;
        grid[4][9] = 2;
        grid[4][10] = 2;
        grid[9][5] = 2;
        grid[9][6] = 2;
        grid[9][7] = 2;
        grid[9][8] = 2;
        grid[10][8] = 2;
        grid[11][8] = 2;
        grid[12][8] = 2;
        grid[13][8] = 2;
        grid[14][8] = 2;
        grid[10][13] = 2;
        grid[10][12] = 2;
        grid[11][12] = 2;
        grid[12][12] = 2;
        grid[11][13] = 4;
        break;

    case 3:
        grid[1][2] = 2;
        break;

    case 4:
        grid[1][2] = 3;
        grid[1][3] = 3;
        grid[1][4] = 3;
        grid[1][5] = 3;
        grid[1][6] = 3;
        grid[1][7] = 3;
        grid[1][8] = 3;
        grid[2][8] = 3;
        grid[3][8] = 3;
        grid[4][8] = 3;
        grid[5][8] = 3;
        grid[6][8] = 3;
        grid[7][8] = 3;
        grid[8][8] = 3;
        grid[8][7] = 3;
        grid[8][6] = 3;
        grid[8][5] = 3;
        grid[8][4] = 3;
        grid[8][3] = 3;
        grid[8][2] = 3;
        grid[7][2] = 3;
        grid[6][2] = 3;
        grid[5][2] = 3;
        grid[4][2] = 3;
        grid[3][2] = 3;
        grid[3][3] = 3;
        grid[3][4] = 3;
        grid[3][5] = 3;
        grid[4][5] = 3;
        grid[5][5] = 4;
        break;

    case 5:
        grid[1][2] = 3;
        grid[1][3] = 3;
        grid[1][4] = 3;
        grid[2][4] = 3;
        grid[3][4] = 3;
        grid[4][4] = 3;
        grid[5][4] = 3;
        grid[6][4] = 3;
        grid[7][4] = 3;
        grid[8][4] = 3;
        grid[8][5] = 3;
        grid[8][6] = 3;
        grid[8][7] = 3;
        grid[7][7] = 3;
        grid[6][7] = 3;
        grid[6][8] = 3;
        grid[6][9] = 3;
        grid[6][10] = 3;
        grid[6][11] = 3;
        grid[5][11] = 3;
        grid[4][11] = 3;
        grid[4][10] = 3;
        grid[4][9] = 3;
        grid[4][8] = 3;
        grid[3][8] = 3;
        grid[2][8] = 3;
        grid[1][8] = 3;
        grid[1][9] = 3;
        grid[1][10] = 3;
        grid[1][11] = 3;
        grid[1][12] = 3;
        grid[1][13] = 3;
        grid[1][14] = 3;
        grid[1][15] = 3;
        grid[2][15] = 3;
        grid[3][15] = 3;
        grid[4][15] = 3;
        grid[5][15] = 3;
        grid[5][16] = 3;
        grid[5][17] = 3;
        grid[5][18] = 4;
        break;

    case 6:
        grid[1][2] = 3;
        grid[1][3] = 3;
        grid[1][4] = 3;
        grid[2][4] = 3;
        grid[3][4] = 3;
        grid[4][4] = 3;
        grid[5][4] = 3;
        grid[6][4] = 3;
        grid[7][4] = 3;
        grid[8][4] = 3;
        grid[8][5] = 3;
        grid[8][6] = 3;
        grid[8][7] = 3;
        grid[7][7] = 3;
        grid[6][7] = 3;
        grid[6][8] = 3;
        grid[6][9] = 3;
        grid[6][10] = 3;
        grid[6][11] = 3;
        grid[5][11] = 3;
        grid[4][11] = 3;
        grid[4][10] = 3;
        grid[4][9] = 3;
        grid[4][8] = 3;
        grid[3][8] = 3;
        grid[2][8] = 3;
        grid[1][8] = 3;
        grid[1][9] = 3;
        grid[1][10] = 3;
        grid[1][11] = 3;
        grid[1][12] = 3;
        grid[1][13] = 3;
        grid[1][14] = 3;
        grid[1][15] = 3;
        grid[2][15] = 3;
        grid[3][15] = 3;
        grid[4][15] = 3;
        grid[5][15] = 3;
        grid[5][16] = 3;
        grid[5][17] = 3;
        grid[4][2] = 3;
        grid[4][3] = 3;
        grid[4][5] = 3;
        grid[4][6] = 3;
        grid[9][4] = 3;
        grid[10][4] = 3;
        grid[11][4] = 3;
        grid[12][4] = 3;
        grid[13][4] = 3;
        grid[11][3] = 3;
        grid[11][2] = 3;
        grid[9][7] = 3;
        grid[10][7] = 3;
        grid[11][7] = 3;
        grid[12][7] = 3;
        grid[8][8] = 3;
        grid[8][9] = 3;
        grid[8][10] = 3;
        grid[8][11] = 3;
        grid[8][12] = 3;
        grid[9][12] = 3;
        grid[9][10] = 3;
        grid[10][10] = 3;
        grid[11][10] = 3;
        grid[11][11] = 3;
        grid[6][15] = 3;
        grid[7][15] = 3;
        grid[8][15] = 3;
        grid[5][18] = 4;
        break;

    case 7:
        grid[1][9] = 2;
        grid[2][9] = 2;
        grid[3][9] = 2;
        grid[4][9] = 2;
        grid[5][9] = 2;
        grid[5][18] = 2;
        grid[5][17] = 2;
        grid[5][16] = 2;
        grid[5][15] = 2;
        grid[5][14] = 2;
        grid[14][18] = 2;
        grid[14][17] = 2;
        grid[14][16] = 2;
        grid[14][15] = 2;
        grid[14][14] = 2;
        grid[18][9] = 2;
        grid[17][9] = 2;
        grid[16][9] = 2;
        grid[15][9] = 2;
        grid[14][9] = 2;
        grid[11][1] = 2;
        grid[11][2] = 2;
        grid[11][3] = 2;
        grid[11][4] = 2;
        grid[11][5] = 2;
        grid[8][1] = 2;
        grid[8][2] = 2;
        grid[8][3] = 2;
        grid[8][4] = 2;
        grid[8][5] = 2;
        break;

    case 8:
        grid[1][9] = 2;
        grid[2][9] = 2;
        grid[3][9] = 2;
        grid[4][9] = 2;
        grid[5][9] = 2;
        grid[5][18] = 2;
        grid[5][17] = 2;
        grid[5][16] = 2;
        grid[5][15] = 2;
        grid[5][14] = 2;
        grid[5][13] = 2;
        grid[5][12] = 2;
        grid[14][18] = 2;
        grid[14][17] = 2;
        grid[18][9] = 2;
        grid[17][9] = 2;
        grid[16][9] = 2;
        grid[15][9] = 2;
        grid[14][9] = 2;
        grid[13][9] = 2;
        grid[12][9] = 2;
        grid[11][9] = 2;
        grid[10][9] = 2;
        grid[11][6] = 2;
        grid[11][1] = 2;
        grid[11][2] = 2;
        grid[11][3] = 2;
        grid[11][4] = 2;
        grid[11][5] = 2;
        grid[8][1] = 2;
        grid[8][2] = 2;
        grid[8][3] = 2;
        grid[8][4] = 2;
        break;

    case 9:
        grid[1][9] = 2;
        grid[2][9] = 2;
        grid[3][9] = 2;
        grid[4][9] = 2;
        grid[5][9] = 2;
        grid[5][18] = 2;
        grid[5][17] = 2;
        grid[5][16] = 2;
        grid[6][16] = 2;
        grid[7][16] = 2;
        grid[8][16] = 2;
        grid[9][16] = 2;
        grid[10][16] = 2;
        grid[10][17] = 2;
        grid[10][18] = 2;
        grid[18][13] = 2;
        grid[17][13] = 2;
        grid[16][13] = 2;
        grid[15][13] = 2;
        grid[14][13] = 2;
        grid[13][13] = 2;
        grid[13][12] = 2;
        grid[13][11] = 2;
        grid[13][10] = 2;
        grid[14][10] = 2;
        grid[15][10] = 2;
        grid[15][9] = 2;
        grid[15][8] = 2;
        grid[15][7] = 2;
        grid[16][7] = 2;
        grid[17][7] = 2;
        grid[17][6] = 2;
        grid[17][5] = 2;
        grid[17][4] = 2;
        grid[18][4] = 2;
        grid[12][1] = 2;
        grid[12][2] = 2;
        grid[12][3] = 2;
        grid[12][4] = 2;
        grid[12][5] = 2;
        grid[12][6] = 2;
        grid[11][6] = 2;
        grid[10][6] = 2;
        grid[10][5] = 2;
        grid[10][4] = 2;
        grid[10][3] = 2;
        grid[9][3] = 2;
        grid[8][3] = 2;
        grid[7][3] = 2;
        grid[6][3] = 2;
        grid[6][4] = 2;
        grid[6][5] = 2;
        grid[6][6] = 2;
        grid[5][6] = 2;
        grid[4][6] = 2;
        grid[4][5] = 2;
        grid[4][4] = 2;
        grid[4][3] = 2;
        grid[4][2] = 2;
        grid[4][1] = 2;
        break;
    }
}

public static final int WHITE   = 0;
public static final int BLACK   = 1;
public static final int BLUE    = 2;
public static final int YELLOW  = 3;
public static final int GREEN   = 4;

private int[][] grid = null;
private int size = 20;
}
```

Its quite big, hence the reason i didnt post it as im not currently sure whats valid.

Comment: show code for the Room class. But just guessing, I'd try `room.getNumber()` to find the room number of the room object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're asking, but why don't you include a method in `Room` to get the current number, for example:

```
public class Room {
   private int _roomNumber;

   public Room(int roomNumber) {
      _roomNumber = roomNumber;
   }

   public int getRoomNumber() {
      return _roomNumber;
   }
}

public class Robot {
   public void move(Room room) {
      int currentRoom = room.getRoomNumber();
   }
}
```

Comment: I had thought of this, but according to the tutor, we are only working with the main class and the side class. We pull functions and such from the others but dont change them. The basic question im asking is how can i tell the side class the parameter of the "Room room = new Room(9);". This line " if (!obstacle_ahead(room)) " checks the square infront of "robby", the thing we are moving along a grid, but to check the square it needs to know the room that its checking in. Is this too vague?

Comment: The only hint she really gave us was "Your program (let say coursework2.java) knows the room. The move(n) method inside the MyRobot class needs to know that information. How can you pass information from the method in one class to the method in another class?"

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to waste peoples time, i have talked to my tutor and been pointed in the correct direction, thanks.